# How to control which SQL Server instance localhost points to

Tags: sql-server, configuration

I have 2 instances of SQL Server on my PC, one is SQL Server 2008 R2, the other SQL Server 2012.

If I use `LOCALHOST` when connecting to SQL Server, it goes to the SQL Server 2008 R2 instance.

I want it to point to the SQL Server 2012 instance.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: You will probably have to uninstall both, and install 2012 as the default instance, and 2008R2 as the named instance if you want 'localhost' to work for 2012

Comment: You change the connection string to use a named instance (e.g. `LOCALHOST\SQL2012` or whatever you named your 2012 instance). You can't rename an instance or change from default to named, and using hokey client network aliases to get around that will only be confusing (and how would you connect to your default instance if you reroute to the named instance?).

Answer (score 19):

It is very easy using Aliases:
1. Go to SQL Server Configuration. 
2. Click on Aliases and setup localhost => localhost\name of your instance
3. do the same thing under 64bit aliases as well

If you have more than once instance localhost might get confused, therefore go to protocols for you name instance and change IP address to 127.0.0.1 which is localhost

Comment: Just to assist here, 'Aliases' is under *SQL Native Client XX.X Configuration* in the tree.

Comment: also, you need "sql server browser" running for aliases to work.

Comment: also, make sure you have the appropriate protocol enabled: SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for <INSTANCE NAME>. For 32 bit it is SQL Server Network Configuration (32bit) > Protocols for <INSTANCE NAME>.

Answer (score 1):

you should specify the sql server instance name,
for example if the instance name is sql2012

```
localhost\sql2012
```

Comment: The reason for the question is that we have a BI project in VS2010 being worked on by several people in different locations, controlled by TFS. It makes sense for us to do our development locally and so if we all set our connections to localhost then it saves us worrying about checking in machine specific connections over the top of each other. The answers seem to indicate that this is not possible without reinstalls. I'm guessing we each have to set up an alias on our own machines with the same name to achieve this.

Comment: I should add that the team members work for different companies, I'm an independent contractor, my client is a software house with their own developers and their client has a developer too so we can't streamline everyone on to the exact same setup.

Comment: The solution was for us all to set up an alias to our own localhosts with the same name.
So those working on default instances they set an alias of APP1DB to LOCALHOST.
Those with named instances can set an alias for APP1DB to localhost\myNamedInstanceName.

Answer (score -2):

you will need to uninstall / reinstall in order to do this.  I wish it was easier to modify an instance.